# Plane intersection in 3 space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let P1 and P2 be planes with normal vectors n1 and n2. Assume that the planes are not parallel, and let L be their intersection (a line). Show that n1 x n2 is a direction vector for L.

My work so far:

n1 = `<a1 , b1, c1>`

n2 = `<a2, b2, c2>`

n1 x n2 = `i(b1*c2 - b2*c1) - j(a1 * c1 - a2 * c2) + k(a1*b1 - a2*b2)`

= `<b1*c2 - b2*c1, a1 * c1 - a2 * c2, a1*b1 - a2*b2>`

I'm not sure what to do at this point. How would I find L? Or do I even need to?

[image]

EDIT:

This is part of a solution to the problem that isn't geometric.

I'm not sure what direction ratios are, so I don't really understand it.

[image]

Comment: Do note that L will lie on both the planes $P_1$ and $P_2$. Hence L will be perpendicular to both the normals $N_1$ and $N_2$. You already found the direction ratios of L by taking the cross product. You are done.

Comment: @GTXOC Would you please explain the solution to the problem I found? I'm not sure what direction ratios are.

Answer (score 0):

You should prove that the direction vector of $L$ is perpendicular with $n_1$ and $n_2$ by using scalar product.

Comment: How would I find the direction vector of L?

Comment: If you have equations of $P1$ and $P2$, you can compute direction vector by parametrization. If not, you can see that the direction vector is perpendicular $n_1$ and $n_2$ similar ideas of GTX OC. In other hand, $n_1 \times n_2$ is perpendicular with $n_1, n_2$, so they are parallel,...

Comment: I'm not sure how to compute the direction vector by parametrization. How would I start?

Answer (score 0):

A direction vector of the line $L$ is $\vec{PP'}$ where $P(x,y,z)$ and $P'(x',y',z')$ are two distinct points on $L$. Therefore, a direction vector $\vec u=\langle u_x, u_y, u_z\rangle$ of $L$ is a non-trivial solution of the system of linear equations
$$a_1u_x+b_1u_y+c_1u_z=0$$
$$a_2u_x+b_2u_y+c_2u_z=0$$
This system has infinetely many solutions since the planes are not parallel. And the solution of the system is $\vec u=(\vec n_1\times \vec n_2)t$, $t\in\Bbb R$ where $\vec n_i=\langle a_i,b_i,c_i\rangle$, $i=1,2$, are the normal vectors of the given planes.

Note: $\vec n_1\times \vec n_2$ is $$\langle a_1b_2-b_1a_2, c_1a_2-a_1c_2, b_1c_2-c_1b_2\rangle.$$